# Which image is used for thumbnail in List Category Post plugin

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

Which image does the plugin use for the thumbnail? From the customer field "thumbnail" or "featured-image"? What about an option to use "first attached image" or "first image in post" as some other plugins do?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Conter-Q: How many plugins does the repo has? Shure we'll search? Shure - if we search - we'll _find_ the right one?

Comment: @kaiser the questions is properly tagged, you can see what plugin he is talking about if you click on the tag.

Comment: @Fernando I was pointed at the fact (that you're using WPSE as plugin forum) by a mod. Hint: Lots of unanswered Qs :)

Comment: @kaiser yeah, haven't had much time to provide support. But luckily sometimes other users in the community answer questions related to the plugin :)

Comment: @Fernando You smart, lazy bastard ;)

Answer (score 1):

It uses the [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) function:

> Gets Post Thumbnail as set in post's or page's edit screen and returns
>   an HTML image element representing a Post Thumbnail, if there is any,
>   otherwise an empty string.

The other options you mention are not included in the plugin now, but they will be considered for future versions.